# Async function not completing

Tags: image, flutter, async-await, save, flutter-web

I'm trying to write an asynchronous function for saving a drawing with canvas to file. For some reason the function does not complete, meaning the file is not created. I am wondering if the process just takes for a long while, since flutter does not throw any error.

```
  void _saveImage() async {
    final recorder = new ui.PictureRecorder();

    final canvas = new Canvas(recorder);

    MyPainter mypainter = new MyPainter(
      shapes: _shapes,
      lineColor: Colors.amber,
      width: 1.0
    );
    mypainter.paint(canvas,Size(1280, 720));

    final picture = recorder.endRecording();
    final img = await picture.toImage(1280, 720);

    final pngBytes = await img.toByteData(format: ImageByteFormat.png); //This line will not work

    File('/home/filename.png').writeAsBytesSync(await pngBytes.buffer.asInt8List());
  }
```

**Edit: Currently `toByteData` is not supported by flutter web, see** https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/44908.

Comment: tried to add some `print()`s between the steps? if so, what do you see?

Comment: The code runs until line `final pngBytes = await img.toByteData(format: ImageByteFormat.png);` . Also used `try/catch`, but did not see any error.

Comment: hmm, strange, are you sure? toByteData() should work just fine, maybe you have error when writing since /home/filename.png looks suspicious...

Comment: Working fine on android device, after specifying a proper directory.